# Уникальный идентификатор комментатора

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Есть страница не ней любой человек может писать комментарии, регистрация не нужна. Как бороться со спамом и не добросовестными комментаторами ?

Comment: Вкратце! Капча и фильтровать сам комментарий на наличие тегов и других опасных символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Akismet](http://akismet.com/)
- Невидимые капчи для людей (за видимые капчи - отрывать руки, во всяком случае за капчи уровня рекапчи и прочих зашумлённых картинок)

Answer (score 1):

Для фильтрации ботов -- использовать каптчу.
Для фильтрации нежелательных сообщений -- ввести на комментарии блэк-лист по ай-пи. Но поскольку нет регистрации, пострадать могут все пользователи, зашедшие с этого ай-пи.